# Cross Domain Http Post data

Tags: cross-domain

> Help!!!!!!!!!!
>   I am stuck by the annoying cross domain issue. Domain A wants to post to domain B.

```
$http_({
    'method': 'POST',
    'url':'https://domainB.com/api/v5.php?rpc=/items/get',
    'data': {'businessId': 1}
})
```

> But the request is always failing.
>   I keep getting the same thing.

```
Name:v5.php?rpc=/items/get
domainB.com/api/
Method:OPTIONS; 
Status:(canceled);

Request URL:https://domainB.com/api/v5.php?rpc=/items/get
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST 
Origin:http://domainA.com
Referer:http://domainA.com/html/dashboard.html
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
rpc:/items/get
```

> The server side configuration:
>
> ```
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type"
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS"
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
> ```
>
> I also try to force the Content-Type to be text/plain, but still cannot work. Do I need to do some additional processing on the backend? Help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> When setting headerAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials to true, you
>   cannot use a wildcard for header Access-Control-Allow-Origin. That is,
>   a specific host must be specified

Duplicated issue: [Cross-domain AJAX withCredentials, PHP returns header content-lenght, but no content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114081/cross-domain-ajax-withcredentials-php-returns-header-content-lenght-but-no-con)

Comment: I added my host to the origin, but still got the same error. Did I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried only to set "Allow-Origin" to the wildcard and leave the rest?

Comment: I only keep the origin one, still no luck.

Comment: Try different a different programming language to access the data, so you maby identify if this still is a crossdomain issue or a non working codebase.

Comment: This api seems good. If I put data in 'params' instead of 'data', then I could get the results.