# Issues setting session cookies in other subdomain

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, session-cookies

I've been tumbling around for a while on the HTTP set-cookie topic but I'm not making any progress. My situation goes as follows:

My API is hosted on api.mysite.com and I have an admin dashboard on admin.mysite.com. I make a POST request from admin.mysite.com to api.mysite.com/login to verify credentials and it returns the session cookie. The cookie configuration is:

```php
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 36000,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => '.mysite.com.co',
    'secure' => 1,
    'httponly' => 0,
    'samesite' => 'None'
]);
```

The response seems okay:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 04 Nov 2021 16:22:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://admin.mysite.com
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, accept, authorization, client-security-token, Cache-Control, X-Mashape-Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Security-Policy, Location
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Upgrade: h2
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=hash; expires=Fri, 05-Nov-2021 02:22:57 GMT; Max-Age=36000; path=/; domain=.mysite.com; secure; SameSite=None
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 549
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

But the cookie is not stored. However, it is stored if I make the request from api.mysite.com/testCookies to api.mysite.com/login so it seems to be a domain/site problem (maybe CORS?)

I will appreciate any guidance on this topic.

Comment: Can we assume the `mysite.com.co` in your PHP is a typo? since that won't work with the `mysite.com` domains. Please inspect your browsers cookie store with development tools or a plugin to see how it is stored. If you explicitly include the domain it should work for all subdomains of that domain as you expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-domain AJAX withCredentials, PHP returns header content-length, but no content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114081/cross-domain-ajax-withcredentials-php-returns-header-content-length-but-no-con)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114081/cross-domain-ajax-withcredentials-php-returns-header-content-length-but-no-con). The keypoint is the usage of `withCredentials` property. Not sure though, why do I have to send them even if the cookies are originated on subdomain A and set on subdomain B.